# How to add a class to protobuf-net

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

i'm using protobuf-net and i like it so far but one thing is bugging me.
I have a class that i would like to use in a message but its not in my source.

like so:
`[ProtoContract]
class Test{ 
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Otherclass Attr {get;set}
}`

but ProtoBuf does not know how to serialize Otherclass and i cant access the code of it.
So i need to tell it how to do it but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In v1 you can't, unless it happens to have xmlaerializer or datacontractserializer attributes. Well, that isn't *quite* true... There *is* a [GlobalOptions](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/branches/v1/protobuf-net/GlobalOptions.cs) toggle that should work in theory, but is not very tolerant if the type changes, as it is inferring a lot.

The better option here is to look at "v2", which is available as an alpha download. Your attributed types should be fine, but you can also tell the type-model how to handle unattributed types; this is all via RuntimeTypeModel.

Comment: thx, but the ALPHA in the name was too scary to look at it in length.

Comment: @Killili the `GlobalOptions` may work - otherwise, using a separate DTO layer is your best option, i.e. re-map the data to something you control

Comment: just a question more: wouldnt it be nice to add a callback for unkown types? So the programmer could add custom handling, like returning a list of ProtoMemberAtrributes to describe the order and names?

Comment: @Killili that isn't an unreasonable question; but that type of additional metadata is already part of what v2 introduces. Adding that into v1 would be more work than finishing v2.